# Why did Looney Tunes characters become hostile to each other while they were good childhood friends?

Tags: looney-tunes

When I first watched the 2002-2005 series [*Baby Looney Tunes*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_Looney_Tunes) I wondered what was the significance of making this series while the characters were hostile to each other as adults from the first episodes of *Looney Tunes*, and why they became hostile to each other as adults while they were good childhood friends.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're trying to apply the rules of continuity to a series that has absolutely *zero* continuity.

Events that happen in one *Looney Tunes* cartoon are completely ignored by the next one. Episodes end with characters being arrested, injured, humiliated, driven to madness, or even killed, only for them to turn up in the next cartoon perfectly fine.

*Baby Looney Tunes* is generally considered to be a spin-off of *Looney Tunes*, rather than a prequel. Its events should not be considered to have any bearing on the events of the original series - you should not assume that there was some unseen falling-out between the characters that explains why they're friends as children but enemies as adults, because the two shows aren't really connected.

As for "the significance of making the series", that's simply that [*Muppet Babies*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muppet_Babies_(1984_TV_series)) - a similar non-canon spin-off - was insanely popular, [everyone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Pup_Named_Scooby-Doo) [else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_%26_Jerry_Kids) was making "baby-fied" spin-offs of their characters, and Warner Bros. wanted a piece of the pie. That's all there is to it.

Comment: You mean it wasn't because Daffy got together with Lola Bunny behind Bugs' back?!?